# Split value from StringCollection to get as parameters

Tags: c#, asp.net

how to split into a string array and pass them to command parameters or hiddenfield, just need to split the string `"S0010M,AZI002M,3,12/26/2013 12:00:00 AM,VDIQ20"`

to pass with parameters like

```
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealerCode", "S0010M");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", "AZI002M");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", 33);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpireDate", "12/26/2015");
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", "VDIQ20");
```

i have big problem about this .. please can you help me to fix this , beaus still learning the subject..

after click on Return button , take the data from gridview, it can be more than one rows.

```
    protected void btnReturn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int rowIndex = 0;

        StringCollection SetDEL_Stores = new StringCollection();

        if (ViewState["CurrentData"] != null)
        {
            DataTable dtCurrentTable = (DataTable)ViewState["CurrentData"];
            DataRow drCurrentRow = null;

            if (dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                for (int i = 1; i <= dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    var DealerCode = HFDealerCode.Value;
                    var ItemIdentityCode = (Label)GridViewSalesReturn.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[2].FindControl("ItemIdentityCode");
                    var Qty = (Label)GridViewSalesReturn.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[8].FindControl("Quantity");
                    var ExpireDate = (Label)GridViewSalesReturn.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[6].FindControl("ExpireDate");
                    var BatchNumber = (Label)GridViewSalesReturn.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[7].FindControl("BatchNumber");

                    CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo("en-GB");

                    SetDEL_Stores.Add(DealerCode + "," + ItemIdentityCode.Text + "," + decimal.Parse(Qty.Text) + "," + DateTime.ParseExact(ExpireDate.Text, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "," + BatchNumber.Text);

                    rowIndex++;
                }

                    InsertDEL_Stores(SetDEL_Stores);
            }
        }
    }
```

//in InsertDEL_Stores(SetDEL_Stores); event , taking the stringline separated with "," ,,

```
    private void InsertDEL_Stores(StringCollection SC_PurLinr)
    {
        String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DEL_Stores_IU", con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealerCode", SC_PurLinr[0]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", SC_PurLinr[1]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", SC_PurLinr[2]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpireDate", SC_PurLinr[3]);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", SC_PurLinr[4]);

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        con.Close();
    }
```

Comment: Why you need to work with a string collection when there are more powerful construct like Dictionaries or just Lists?

Comment: Why would you want to pass the date as a string instead of as a `DateTime`?

Comment: please can you just explain me about any appropriate methods to apply with this situation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear why you need a string collection first. If you want to keep the contents of the single rows in the GridView then start defining a class for your items where every single field is typed correctly (string for strings, numeric for numerics and datetime for dates) Copying the content of the grid in a string collection is just a waste of time and memory because every time you need to use the values stored in the string collection you need to find the correct string and split it to the individual fields.

I could just offer a pseudocode here because I haven't the possibility to test it.

(As an example I have named this class MyItem, but you could call it as you wish)

```
public class MyItem
{
   public string DealerCode;
   public string ItemCode;
   public int Quantity;
   public Datetime ExpireDate;
   public string BatchNumber;
}
```

Then in your loop

```
// To keep the content of the grid keyed on the BatchNumber field   
Dictionary<string, MyItem> items = new Dictionary<string, MyItem>();

for (int rowIndex = 0; i < dtCurrentTable.Rows.Count; i++)
{
   MyItem itm = new MyItem();
   itm.DealerCode = HFDealerCode.Value.ToString();
   itm.ItemCode = GetGridValue(rowIndex, 2, "ItemIdentityCode"); 
   itm.Quantity = Convert.ToDecimal(GetGridValue(rowIndex, 8, "Quantity");
   itm.ExpireDate = Convert.ToDateTime(GetGridValue(rowIndex, 6, "ExpireDate");
   itm.BatchNumber = GetGridValue(rowIndex, 7, "BatchNumber");

   // Add the item to the dictionary for future reuses, however if you just want to store
   // the item in the database this line is not needed
   items.Add(itm.BatchNumber, itm);

   // notice that the storing is executed inside the loop that extracts the values
   // so every row is updated/inserted in the database
   InsertDEL_Stores(itm);
}
```

`GetGridValue` is a method that you should write taking the parameters passed and returning a string with the value searched on the current row of your gridview. This could be simple as

```
string GetGridValue(int rowIndex, int cellIndex, string controlName)
{
    Control c = GridViewSalesReturn.Rows[rowIndex].Cells[cellIndex].FindControl(controlName);
    return (c != null ? c.Value.ToString() : "");
}
```

but you need to test it for its correctness.

However, after that you have an istance of `MyItem` class that you could store in the dictionary for future reuses or just pass it to the database working procedure

```
private void InsertDEL_Stores(MyItem itm)
{
    String strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CBConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_DEL_Stores_IU", con))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DealerCode", itm.DealerCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Code", itm.ItemCode);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Qty", itm.Quantity);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ExpireDate", itm.ExpireDate);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@BatchNumber", itm.BatchNumber);
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

I am aware that this code could raise more questions than the one that you try to resolve, neverless I think that this is more OOP than a simple string split

Comment: Mr @Steve i don't have words to say thank you .... thank you so mush ... that was the way i wanted.,, thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

To split a string using commas as the separator character do the following

```
String[] values = str.split(",");
```

Then you can access the array in the following way

```
values[0];
```

But since your question is a bit confusing I suggest you read well the comments by other contributors what best suits your needs, how you are passing those values to the command parameters. Certainly,  dictionaries and lists are more efficient than String collections